# Background Interactive push notification iOS 9

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I have a requirement to make phone call/send message from app on selection of any option from interactive push notification on lock screen (app can be closed/background/suspended). I tried UIApplication OpenUrl method to make a call it doesn't work. I have done some research and found that app doesn't allow to make phone call without user consent when app is in background.

One way I found was to launch the application on push notification click and then use OpenUrl to make phone call. But to achieve this every time one need to unlock the phone. (which I don't want)

Is there any way that without unlocking phone on click of push notification we can make phone call ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On iOS, there is no way to place call with the dialer **without** the user's consent via user interaction (it has to open the phone's dialer...). The only way I could imagine this could be done on iOS is if your app had a VoIP client embedded in it and thus bypass the device's dialer and used your own "private" (leased/co-op/rented) VoIP network

Comment: Is it possible to open camera from lock screen on click of interactive notification ?

Comment: Sure, a user taps on your alert in the Notification Center that opens your app and your app opens the camera....

Comment: In iOS 9 we can see camera icon at bottom of lock screen. Can that be open on click of notification ? Basically requirement is to skip pass-code and open camera app.